# Experience/Examples using Nordic nRF52840 (BLE) with C#?

Tags: c#, node.js, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

Does anyone have experience using the Nordic NRF52840 with a C# app to act as a receiver?

I'm trying to communicate with an Onset InTemp thermometer and although I've had quite a bit of success with the native Windows 10 BLE, I'm having some problems.  See: [C#, BLE. Why does GetGattServicesAsync hang forever? Is there a work around such as turning off/on BLE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63819254/c-ble-why-does-getgattservicesasync-hang-forever-is-there-a-work-around-such?noredirect=1#comment112853505_63819254) for details.

Nordic advertises that they only have C++, Python and Node.js libraries.  See https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/65516/using-nrf52840-dongle-as-receiver-client-for-onset-thermometer for example.  I need either a C# library OR perhaps some hints on how to build the C++ library with Visual Studio (there are no instructions that I can see) and setup the interop layer (method signature etc.).  I think this would go much faster if I saw an example :). And I'm guessing this type of work has been done before.

Another possibility is to call the Node.js libraries from C# which I understand is possible but again, I'd need some initial examples.  Probably more so as I've never used Node.js either on its own or from C#.

Thanks, Dave

Comment: Why not use C++ version from C#? I'm no expert, but that seems like the closest compatibility.

Comment: Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/7665043/l3l-aze.  That's probably what I'll do, but it would be nice if there were some examples to look at.  As I recall from limited P/Invoke and Interop experience, there are method signatures and the like to write.  Plus there is the problem of actually compiling the C++ code.  Thanks for reading.

Comment: Excellent point; I'm not deep into the C family personally as it's too difficult past "the basics", and I hadn't considered that. There are open source Node and Python bindings that would help towards a library but that would greatly delay progress on your desired project and require upkeep over time. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15136952/7665043) has some ideas for using Node and C# together. Node is not very different from JS and since you're already used to C#'s modularized style it may be easier than going from learning JS right to Node.

Comment: Also, NordicSemi and their code are on GitHub, and the [readme for the driver](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/pc-ble-driver) has short compilation instructions that mention VS by name, so it should be pretty simple.